# JUnit assertEquals failing with HashSet

Tags: java, junit, addressbook

I was doing some JUnit tests for the  [AddressBook](https://se-edu.github.io/addressbook-level4/)
and kept failing to implement one of my tests. Here is that test:

```
@Test
public void parseIndices_collectionWithValidIndices_returnsIndexSet() throws Exception {
    Set<Index> actualIndexSet = ParserUtil.parseIndices(Arrays.asList(VALID_INDEX_1, VALID_INDEX_2));

    Index index = Index.fromOneBased(Integer.valueOf(VALID_INDEX_1));
    Index index2 = Index.fromOneBased(Integer.valueOf(VALID_INDEX_2));
    Set<Index> expectedIndexSet = new HashSet<>();
    expectedIndexSet.add(index);
    expectedIndexSet.add(index2);

    assertEquals(expectedIndexSet, actualIndexSet);
}
```

The output shows as follows:

[image: Output of running test]
It shows that they are equal but somehow the assert keeps failing. I then tried asserting the 2 actualIndexSets (as shown below) to see if they would pass the test but it still failed with the same result which is weird.

```
@Test
public void parseIndices_collectionWithValidIndices_returnsIndexSet() throws Exception {
    Set<Index> actualIndexSet = ParserUtil.parseIndices(Arrays.asList(VALID_INDEX_1, VALID_INDEX_2));
    Set<Index> actualIndexSet2 = ParserUtil.parseIndices(Arrays.asList(VALID_INDEX_1, VALID_INDEX_2));

    Index index = Index.fromOneBased(Integer.valueOf(VALID_INDEX_1));
    Index index2 = Index.fromOneBased(Integer.valueOf(VALID_INDEX_2));
    Set<Index> expectedIndexSet = new HashSet<>();
    expectedIndexSet.add(index);
    expectedIndexSet.add(index2);

    assertEquals(actualIndexSet2, actualIndexSet);
}
```

The problem here is that something is obviously not right because it fails when I assert 2 sets of the actualIndexSet which are the same given that assert for the Index class is working fine.

Comment: Do you have proper hashCode / equals on your Index class?

Comment: OMG i did not @Override hashCode at all, this solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return zeroBasedIndex;
}
```

Overriding hashCode method in Index class sloved it.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet overrides equals; it checks if first set contains all from the second set.

The only possible reason is that your Index class is not overriding equals.
when method containsAll will be called, it will iterate over all index elements and will check if the result of equals is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the `equals` method and how it's defined in the `Index` class.

I would recommend to use a library like apache commons to solve that for you:

```
CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(expectedIndexSet, actualIndexSet)
```